# Functions used in the Weil pairing

Tags: algebraic-geometry, notation, elliptic-curves, divisors-algebraic-geometry, torsion-groups

I'm using the definition of the Weil Pairing from Silverman's book on elliptic curves. When he defines the functions used in the pairing, he writes:

[image]

**I have two related questions about what is written here:**

1) What is the difference between $[m]*(T) - [m]*(\mathcal{O})$ and $m(T)-m(\mathcal{O})$ ? (From the second and first centred equations, respectively)

2) Why is the sum on the right hand side of the second centred equation equal to  $\mathcal{O}$? I'm not sure how to use the parenthetical remark to see this result.

Answer (score 1):

$m(T)$ is the divisor got by adding $m$ copies of the divisor $(T)$.

$[m]^*(T)$ is the inverse image of the divisor $(T)$ under the
multiplication-by-$m$ map $[m]:E\to E$. It is the sum of the $m^2$
$T'$ solving $[m](T')=T$.

Comment: Let me see if I've got this right: $[m](T)$ is the divisor equal to the sum of all $(T^\prime)$ satisfying $[m]T^\prime = T$ ?

Comment: @Alex That's $[m]^*(T)$.

Comment: Yes, my mistake. That answers my question, so thank you. It seems like a very peculiar choice of notation though.